# ODE solution for a simple case

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to solve this but I can't not fix the problem :( please help me.

a,b,f and d positive vale.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = a*y'[t] == b*y[t]^2 + f*y[t]+d;
DSolve[{eqns, y[0] == 0, y[t0] == 1}, y[t], t]
y[t] = x'[t]/x[t];
DSolve[{eqns, x[t0] = x0}, x[t], t]
```

Comment: First `DSolve `: You use 2 initial conditions, one is enough for an ode of first order. `t0` isn't defined!  Is `y[t] = x'[t]/x[t]`intended to transform the ode?

Comment: Okay how can put two initial conditions? t0 is positive and I just want the solution with t0. I would like to use the soluion of y[t] from first DSolve and put to another Dsolve

Comment: That means: Your 2nd ode is `y[t]==x'[t]/x[t]`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly,  you might solve the problem in one step

```
sol=DSolve[{a*y'[t] == b*y[t]^2 + f*y[t]+ d, 
y[t] == x'[t]/x[t],
y[t0] == 1}, {x, y}, t]
```

Comment: exactly this is what I mean but other problem is come up is : 
Cos[(Sqrt[4 b d -  f^2] (t + (-Sqrt[4 b d - f^2] t0 + 2 a ArcTan[(2 b Sqrt[4 b d - f^2] + f Sqrt[4 b d - f^2])/(4 b d - f^2)])/Sqrt[4 b d - f^2]))/(2 a)]^(-(a/b))  this part should be (Sinh [b/a..t]   /Sinh[b/a...t0]   )^(-a/b)

Comment: Simplify[
 DSolve[{a*y'[t] == b*y[t]^2 + f*y[t] + d, y[t] == x'[t]/x[t], 
   y[t0] == 1}, {x, y}, t], 
 Assumptions -> {t0 > 0, a > 0, b > 0, f > 0, d > 0}]

Comment: This is the solution Exp[-f/2b (t-t0)]*(Sinh [-b/a..t] /Sinh[-b/a...t0] )^(-a/b)

Comment: @FelipeDura Your comments are difficult to understand if you do not tell how you got your results!

Comment: Can you see the solution now?

Comment: My answer gives you a solution you asked for. It 's your turn to compare with the formulas (I don't know where they come from!) found in the book.